# Is Reactive Programming related to react native?

Tags: react-native, reactive

I think

> ***react native***

is a framework which we use to create hybrid apps &

> ***reactive programming*** 
>   provides us some libraries like Rx Java, Rx Android which we can use for native apps.

Is both **reactive programming & react native** has any similarities?

**Is both are related anywhere?**

Comment: They are not related, Reactive programming is a concept, whether React Native is language.

Comment: No, it is two completely different things. React Native is a framework based on the react javascript framework.
Reactive programming is a  programming paradigm.

Comment: @Priyadharshini please see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html. `How to use in Android` is not a good question.

Comment: @Khemraj My question is about, How to build android apps using React Native?

Comment: `Is Reactive Programming related to react native?` isn't this your question. Then please edit your question as needed. Or please ask new question.

Answer (score 2):

Well react-native is a library/platform allowing you to build native apps using javascript. Reactive programming is a programming paradigm. There are not related in any way.